# How to use multiple criteria with COUNTIF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-2003

INPUT:

[image]

This is the format of the OUTPUT desired:

[image]

OUTPUT for example INPUT:

[image]

The problem is, I don't know how to use COUNTIF with several criteria.

The "dream function" [that doesn't work] would look like this in cell D3:

```
=(COUNTIF($M$2:$M$65535;boy) AND (COUNTIF($N$2:$N$65535;">0")-COUNTIF($N$2:$N$65535;">4")) AND (COUNTIF($O$2:$O$65535;WILMS))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use the `COUNTIFS` formula in Excel 2007. In prior versions, you will have to use an array formula

Comment: http://www.yogeshguptaonline.com/2009/10/excel-formulas-countif-multiple.html

Comment: It appears there are multiple values in some cells of column N. The formula is not going to be able to see them as separate values, therefore will not see 0,4 as 0 and 4. These need to be in there own rows/cells.

Comment: Is that not continental notation for 3.4 ? Here in Spain the , and . are transposed. 1.000,2 is just over a thousand.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/hu-hu/excel-help/szorzatosszeg-HP005209293.aspx

Comment: Did you make it work with SUMPRODUCT lance?

Answer (score 1):

Add a column that classifies by range (say P2=`IF(N2>=9,"R4",IF(N2>4,"R3",IF(N2>1,"R2","R1")))` & copy down) then use a pivot table. With some appearance modification (and using Excel 2007) the result seems close enough to serve:

[image: Pivot table example]